# Can I call a function in a script from a library script made by myself?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

Here is my library code:

```
function simpleEdit(){
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    cell.setValue('Simple edit made by script');
    // Calling a custom script function after doing edit
    customfunc();
}
```

`customfunc()` is outside the library in other script but in same project.

Here is its code:

```
function customfunc() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('Hi');
}
```

Script calling library function
    `function s()
{
Demog.simpleEdit();
}`
 Demog is the library identifier

Comment: Yes - this should work - as long as these functions are in the same scope.

Comment: but it does not work when I call it through function s.. library code is added as a resource library.. there is no library script code in project as such

Comment: Is your library published? Is demog the library identifier? Does it have dev mode on? There's lot of things you could be doing wrong, and all of then are in the documentation, just rubber duck from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works. If you have a library published with two script files in it. All the methods not marked as private will be accessible to script the is utilizing the library.

But to let you know getActiveSheet() or getActiveSpreadsheet() will not work in a library. Even if the script you published was contained in a spreadsheet. It will always return null.